# Entity Framework table relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

### Introduction

- I am new to Entity Framework
- I am using Code-first

### Use-case

I have to following tables

```
[Table("TBL_UserVariant")]
public class UserVariant
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int VarId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Table("TBL_UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string eMail { get; set; }
}
```

I want TBL_UserProfile to refer a list of all TBL_UserVariant entries where TBL_UserProfile::UserId == TBL_UserVariant::UserId

The following is an example of my aim

```
[Table("TBL_UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string eMail { get; set; }

    public UserVariant[] variants;
}
```

Where 'UserProfile::variants' should include a list of items where 'TBL_UserProfile::UserId == TBL_UserVariant::UserId'

### Question

Is this directly possible using EF ? OR, should I implement a wrapper populating 'UserProfile::variants' ~manually~ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just add a navigation property to the UserProfile entity.

```
    [Table("TBL_UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string eMail { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserVariant> UserVariants { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How would EF know to have only the rows where 'TBL_UserProfile::UserId == TBL_UserVariant::UserId' ?

Comment: When you first use the UserVariants property, EF queries for records from the TBL_UserVariant table where the UserIds are equal. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you should need. EF will take care of the rest.

```
[Table("TBL_UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserVariant> Variants { get; set; }
}

[Table("TBL_UserVariant")]
public class UserVariant
{
    [Key]
    public int VarId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is that you want to have one `UserProfile`, mapped to Many `UserVariants`

In that case you'll need to add a collection to your UserProfile class.

```
public virtual ICollection<UserVariant> UserVariants { get; set; }
```

You'll also need to fix the `[Key]` property on the UserVariant class as I believe it should be on VarId. You can then just specify a navigation property

```
[Key]
public int VarId { get; set; }
public UserProfile User { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

As an aside, your naming conventions are all over the place. Don't prefix your table names with `TBL_`. Capitalise all your properties/Columns. e.g. `Email` not `eMail`

Comment: How would this gaurunte UserVariants to include only those entries where 'TBL_UserProfile::UserId == TBL_UserVariant::UserId' ?

Comment: EF will handle that. Try profiling the SQL code it generates and you'll see how.